# Using dplyr, I want to remove a common word from a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing this in R
I have column named "region" which consists of values as below:

```
region_24,
region_67,
region_30,
region_26,
region_29
```

I want to remove "region_" from this column.

Can you please help me with the coding using dplyr?
using following:

- filter
- replace
- remove
- delete
- apply

What are the different various ways of doing this?

Comment: I would appreciate if specific answers can be given with reference to queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
test$region <-  gsub("[region_]", "", test$region)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` :

```
transform(df, V1 = sub('region_', '', V1))

#  V1
#1 24
#2 67
#3 30
#4 26
#5 29
```

Or if you want to extract only the numbers from the column, we can use `parse_number`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>% mutate(V1  = parse_number(V1))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("region_24", "region_67", "region_30", 
"region_26", "region_29")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```